# how to implement wishlist to have unknown number of items - Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-models

I want to implement a wishlist for my online shop project which is a Django project.

I already implemented `WishListItem` table and due to my scenario, I used `GenericForeignKey`:

```
class WishListItem(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    add_to_list_date = models.DateTimeField(_('add to list date'), null=True, blank=True)
    
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

now I have to implement `Wishlist` table.  1- the user may have **many wishlists**. 2- each wish list have an unknown number of `WishlistItems`s. here is what I have in mind:

```
class QuoteList(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item = models.ForeignKey(WishListItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but I know it's not quite good. **how to add many `wishlistitem`s to one `quotelist`?**

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @iklinac  how many `ManyToManyField` should I declare?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a little short on details. For example, what is a `quotelist`? Further are 'Wishlists` predefined sets the user selects from or does the user create them as needed. If predefined then a M:M relationship exists between Users and Wishlists. The same can be asked for Wishlists to WishlistItems.

However, your description seems to indicate both Wishlists and associated  WishlistItems are strictly dependent on user construction. If this is the case then you just need two 1:M relationships - Users:Wishlists and Wishlists:WishlistItems as follows:

```
create table users(user_id  integer generated always as identity 
                  , name    text
                  -- other attributes 
                  , constraint user_pk primary key (user_id) 
                  ) ; 
              
create table  wish_lists( wish_list_id integer generated always as identity 
                        , user_id      integer
                        , description  text
                        -- other attributes
                        , constraint wish_list_pk primary key (wish_list_id)
                        , constraint wish_list_2_user_fk
                                     foreign key(user_id)
                                     references users(user_id)
                        ) ;
                        
create table  wish_list_items( wish_lists_item_id integer generated always as identity 
                             , wish_list_id       integer
                             , description        text
                             -- other attributes
                             , constraint wish_list_items_pk 
                                          primary key (wish_list_id)
                             , constraint wish_list_item_2_wish_listr_fk
                                          foreign key(wish_list_id)
                                          references wish_lists(wish_list_id)
                        ) ;
```

I do not know how to define it in your obfuscation layer (Django) so I must leave that translation to you.